# How to resolve 'netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.' in syslog on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5?

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel

When I install customized RHEL 6.5 with no GUI, on the Virtualized Platform like Esx Server. I am constantly getting, kernel message `netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.`. And this message is dumped into the /var/log/messages file. But When I install RHEL 6.5 without any customization, and select `minimal` during package selection. I am not getting this kernel message at all.

What could be the problem?

As per RHEL 6.5 documentation: `https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.5_Technical_Notes/net-snmp.html`

The RHEL6.5 has fixed this issue in BZ#927474.
But How it is related to net-snmp is not clear?

As when you install RHEl6.5 with/without snmp package it doesn't give any kernel error message?

But when I install the customized RHEL6.5, with selected set of packages, It starts dumping the error message.

Moreover from the RHEL documentation link If the fix is required in net-snmp daemon, then it should always be running, which is not the case, when you don't install the net-snmp package itself. And Still we don't get the kernel message.

Any pointers to solve this, would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=115c9b81928360d769a76c632bae62d15206a94a) is explanation from kernel developers.

Comment: I don't have the kernel source code. So I can't comment whether the RHEL 6.5 have implemented it or not. Moreover It doesn't solves my problem. Appreciate the link you shared.